# How to use IBMIoTF for node.js in a WebApplication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, watson-iot

I tested the IBMIoTF in a node.js server and it worked well.
IBMIoTF you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmiotf

Now I want to use the IBMIoTF in a WebApplication and I notice this little note in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmiotf#load-the-library-in-browser

***Load the library in browser***
load iotf-client-bundle.js or iotf-client-bundle-min.js from the dist directory

I also took a look into the http://browserify.org/, but I am not able to get it working.

It is able to load the library in the ***index.html***

```
<script src="libs/iotf/iotf-client-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

, but how can I create a object instance in the angular module?

**Option 1**

I am not able to use require in a WebApplication.

```
var config = {
                       "org": "THEORG",
                       "id": "IOT_WEB_APPLICATION",
                       "auth-key": "THEKEY",
                       "auth-token": "THETOKEN",
                       "type" : "shared"
               };

var IotClient = require('ibmiotf');
var iotClient = new IotClient.IotfApplication(config);
```

In this situation I get

```
angular.js:14110 ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**Option 2**

I also tried to use a object, I found in iotf-client.js file.

```
  module.exports = {
    IotfDevice: _IotfDevice['default'],
    IotfManagedDevice: _IotfManagedDevice['default'],
    IotfGateway: _IotfGateway['default'],
    IotfManagedGateway: _IotfManagedGateway['default'],
    IotfApplication: _IotfApplication['default']
  };
```

and did a implementation like this in my controller:

```
var config = {
               "org": "THEORG",
               "id": "IOT_WEB_APPLICATION",
               "auth-key": "THEKEY",
               "auth-token": "THETOKEN",
               "type" : "shared"
             };
var iotClient = new IotfApplication(config);
```

Here I get:

```
angular.js:14110 ReferenceError: IotfApplication is not defined
```

These options didn't work, but how to create a instance for the IBMIoTF?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to browserify the ibmiotf as part of your buildprocess:
1. in your package.json add dependency to ibmiotf npm
2. do `npm install`
3. add a script command to your package.json for browserify/uglify like this

```
"scripts": {
"build": "browserify your.js | uglifyjs -m -c warnings=false > bundle.js"
}
```

4. do `npm build`, this will produce a bundle.js with all your javascript files and the dependencies specified to bundle.js
5. Include the bundle.js in your web html file. `...<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
6. in "your.js" do something like this

   `var config = require(YOURCONFIG);
   var deviceType = "YOURDEVICETYPE";
   var appClient = new client.IotfApplication(config);
   appClient.connect();
   appClient.on("connect", function () {
   console.log("Connected");
   appClient.subscribeToDeviceEvents(deviceType);
       });
   appClient.on("deviceEvent", function (deviceType, deviceId, eventType, format, payload) {
           console.log("Device Event from :: "+deviceType+" : "+deviceId+" of event "+eventType+" with payload : "+payload);
       });`

Comment: Hello Rene, thanks for the feedback. I did a basic sample here https://github.com/thomassuedbroecker/browserfied-ibmiotf-webapplication for a angular web application. Regards Thomas